# iPad Default dropdown box

Tags: css, ipad

I am trying to change the background color and font for the dropdown box on the iPad. This is just a standard HTML page being viewed in a browser within an application.

Just to make sure we are all on the same page I would like to change the white background to gray (just an example).

I have tried stuff with CSS, here is an example.

### HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value=''>- Select a location -</option>
    <option>East Anglia</option>
</select>
```

### CSS:

```
option {
    background: #000;
}
```

There are a few CSS files linking in and I guess something could be stopping it or setting the background (I have tried using `!important`) but I don't think that is the case as from my search on the web I ran into a few posts saying its not possible to change and you should use a jQuery dropdown.

Any information on this would be great.

[image: iPad Dropdown]

Comment: *" I ran into a few posts saying its not possible to change and you should use a jQuery dropdow"*. Whilst it doesn't necessarily have to be jQuery (hell you can build a hover-based dropdown with all-CSS and 1 line of native JS), fact remains that styling native dropdowns sucks and is impossible on IOS.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Indeed, the posts I read linked to some jQuery one that looks exactly like the iPad one (just to clarify that). So it is 100% **impossible** to change the default iPad dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done, creating your own drop down is the next best option.